# Spacy - number of lemma

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, spacy, lemmatization

I'm using spacy to replace every word in a sentence with a number/code, after I use the vector as a input of a recurrent neural network.

```
import spacy
 str="basing based base"
 sp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
 sentence=sp(str)
 for w in sentence:
    print(w.text,w.lemma)
```

In the first layer of Neural network with keras, the Embedding layer, I have to know the max number of words in the look up table, someone know this number?
Thank you

Comment: How do you get the integer indices that you're going to use to get the embeddings from the layer? Is it the internal ID from spacy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lemma indices are in fact hashes, so there is not a continuous row of indices from 0 to the number of vocabulary entries. Even `sp.vocab.strings["randomnonwordstring#"]` gives you an integer.

For entry "base", the ID is `4715552063986449646` in `sp.vocab` (note it is a shared vocab both for forms and lemmas). You would never fit such a number of embeddings in a memory.

The correct solution is creating a dictionary transforming words into indices based on what you have in your training data.